# stop executing a function without exiting the application

Tags: android

Following is my code:

```
try 
{
    usrID=client.callString("VerifyUsrnameAndPswd", userName.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
}
catch (JSONRPCException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
    Log.e("error", "client.callString exception: "+e.toString());
    e.printStackTrace();
// If this condition is true, then no need to go ahead
}
// some steps of remaining code
```

I do not want to execute the steps after the catch block, when there is no internet connection. But I don't even want to exit the application. Hence cannot use `final()`.

Please suggest me some function to stop the further execution without exiting the application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You shoud use `continue` or `break` or `return` in catch block depending where that code is.

Answer (score 0):

One - you can use `return` statement.

Two - You can set a flag, and according to the flag, you can execute some code, or do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

'return; finish;'
can stop execution